# How to prove $\log_{18}12$ is irrational?

Tags: logarithms

I was trying to prove this through contradiction where I supposed that it was rational but it didnt seem to work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you show even your failed attempts, that can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were rational, say $m/n$ then

$$18^{m/n}=12, \text{  or  } 18^m = 12^n$$

Equivalently, find the respective prime factorizations

$$2^m3^{2m} = 2^{2n}3^n \iff 2^{m-2n} = 3^{n-2m}$$

This gives only the solution $n=m=0$, so the "rational" exponent is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidPeterson beat me to answer this, but I'll answer anyway. $\log_{18}12=x$, where $18^x=12$. Assume $x$ is rational. Then $x=\frac{p}{q},p,q\in\mathbb{Z}, q\neq 0$. We thus have $18^{\frac{p}{q}} = 12\Rightarrow 18^p = 12^q\Rightarrow 2^p 3^{2p} =2^{2q}3^q\Rightarrow 2^{2q-p}=3^{2p-q}$. This gives $p=q=0$ because the bases are different, and so they can only be equal when the exponent is $0,$ which implies $2q-p=2p-q=0\Rightarrow 3q=3p=0\Rightarrow q=p=0$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
suppose
$\log_m n
$
is rational.

I will show that
$m$ and $n$
are powers of the
same integer.

We have
$\dfrac{\log n}{\log m}
=\dfrac{a}{b}
$
where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime positive integers.

Then
$n^b = m^a
$.

Let
$n
=\prod p_i^{n_i}
$
and
$m
=\prod p_i^{m_i}
$.

Then
$\prod p_i^{bn_i}
=\prod p_i^{am_i}
$
so
$bn_i = am_i
$
for all $i$.

Since
$(a, b) = 1$,
$b | m_i$
and
$a | n_i$
so
$m_i = bu_i$
and
$n_i = a v_i
$
where
$u_i$ and $v_i$
are positive integers.

Then
$bn_i
=abv_i
=am_i
=abu_i$
so
$u_i = v_i$.

Therefore
$n
=\prod p_i^{av_i}
=(\prod p_i^{v_i})^a
$
and
$m
=\prod p_i^{bu_i}
=(\prod p_i^{u_i})^b
$.

Therefore
both $n$ and $m$
must be
powers of the same integer
(since
$\prod p_i^{v_i}
=\prod p_i^{u_i}
$).